# A hint for editing posts in regard to Ubuntu documentation

Tags: discussion

I just found out that http://help.ubuntu.com provides a nice feature against link rot.

There exist two URLs:

- [Current Release](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/index.html)
- [Current LTS Release](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/index.html)

They are especially helpful when pointing to the [Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html).